# can we use doctrine and Zend_db_table model side by side?

Tags: zend-framework

I have one small zend project which already uses Zend_db_table model, I am trying to extend this project so that i can use doctrine in new controllers and models leaving the old models as they are. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrapping and API consumption of both DBAL's should be straightforward.

It seems to me that the primary issue is re-using the db connection, That is, one request whose execution path consumes both `Doctrine` and `Zend_Db` should not open separate connections.

It appears that `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` has a method `getWrappedConnection()` which returns - for example - a `PDO` connection (actually a subclass of SPL's `PDO` class, but still an instance of PDO). In principle, you could bootstrap Doctrine first, grab this connection, and somehow "pass this" into the `Zend_Db_Adapter`. However, while I do see a method called `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::getConnection()`, I don't see one called `setConnection()`. Perhaps create a custom subclass for the the desired `Zend_Db` adapter?

The other problem I see is that the `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::getWrappedConnection()` actually opens the connection the db. If we call this during bootstrap and then pass that connection to the `Zend_Db` side, then we will have lost the lazy-connect feature of both DBAL's.

Of course, if no execution path needs to call both `Doctrine` and `Zend_Db`, then perhaps there is no problem. Just bootstrap both of them and let your code call whichever one it needs. And if you have the processing capacity to deal with it, then maybe two connections per request is not a game-killer (though it strikes me as pretty severe).

Just thinking out loud.

Comment: MWOP noted in [this podast](http://voicesoftheelephpant.com/2012/02/21/interview-with-matthew-weier-ophinney/) that one of the goals in the ZF2 `Zend\Db` rewrite is to facilitate connection sharing between `Zend\Db` and `Doctrine2`.